# How to authorize to GitHub API using axios

Tags: axios, github-api, bearer-token

How can I authorize to https://api.github.com using GitHub auth token and axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer AUTH_TOKEN_HERE'
    }
});
let response = await axiosInstance.get('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const fetchRepo = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'token AUTH_TOKEN_HERE',
      }
    });
    console.log(await response);
    return response.data;
  }
```